# How do I make wi-fi calls from a cell phone with no number now associated with it?

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, calls, phone-app, voip, sip

I recently got tired of paying $65+ a month for cell service when I get mostly email. So I dropped my Sprint service in favor of $20 a month, no-contract phone and a Nexus 7, because WiFi is seemingly everywhere. It works great! I have all the service I need, and it's much cheaper.

I still have this nice cell phone, a Nexus S. I enabled the WiFi on it. I'd like to make free WiFi calls on it but it no longer has a number associated with it. I ported that number over to my $20 a month phone. Is there anyway I can get a number associated with this old phone so I can sign up for a free voip service?  Is there anyway I can make voip calls without a number?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to have the same number on two different phones.

On your Nexus S, you could install [Skype](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skype.raider). That will give you FREE VOIP for Skype-to-Skype calls. You don't need a number for this, just an internet connection (and a Skype account, which is free). Take note, however, Skype to mobile / landline is not free.

For other alternatives, search for `voip` in Google Play.

**Edit #1:** I looked around and found [IPKall](http://www.ipkall.com/). It gives you a FREE Washington number. Is this the kind of service you are looking for?

Comment: *It's not possible to have the same number on two different phones.* Sure? I'd say it depends. There are special services for that, at least over here in Europe. You can get a second SIM card, responding to the same number. Of course, this means a little extra fee -- but it is possible.

Comment: @Izzy That's interesting to know. I haven't heard of that kind of service here in the Philippines though. In any case, it's probably not common practice.

Comment: I don't know whether this would work with CDMA devices (where you cannot simply insert a SIM). I just know that at least one provider here in Germany has it in his portfolio, so you can get a second SIM encoded to your phone number. Useful e.g. for devices "fixed" to mobiles (car equipment etc.). Or to have a "deputy" picking up if you don't. You can even configure whether it should ring simultaneously, or only if the "master device" didn't react for X seconds.

Comment: There must be someplace on the web I can find/buy a phone #.  I though I might be able to get one off Google Voice but I can't figure out how to associate the # with this phone.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Joe See my **Edit #1**

Answer (score 1):

***Let's get this right the first time, shall we? : )***

Several options that are offered so far seem to indicate a third-party app will be doing the dialing. However, dependent upon your geographic location, you may be able to activate the native dialer in the Google Nexus S.

Before proceeding, you will need to:

1) Be based in the United States (there are ways around this...!), and;

2) Have a phone number registered for use within the United States (required).

3) Grab a BEvERage of choice.

4) Not be busy for the next 45 minutes. Tell everyone to PFO (please fone others).

5) Remove your SIM-card from your Google Nexus S.

Let's begin!

**I: GET GOOGLE VOICE VIA WEB SIGN-UP**

1) Get a Google Voice account. When going through the setup portion, you need to confirm a secondary number with the account. Use your phone number that you have with your $20/mo phone.

2) Grab an area code that you like (as GVoice calls currently are free throughout USA & Canada, but this may change).

3) GOTO Settings, and enable Google Chat as a client that can make and receive phone calls.

***What if I have a US-based cellphone, but I'm in `country other than USA`?***

Use a proxy or TOR-based service, cloak your exit location with a US-based proxy, and sign-up for the service. BTW, *your welcome*.

**II: GET GOOGLE VOICE VIA ANDROID MARKET**

1) Find "Google Voice" in the Android Market. Alternatively, you can also find the *.apk with a quick Google search if you can't access the installer via the market.

2) Install "Google Voice."

3) When asked about how you want Google Voice to process calls, select "As every time I make a call." You can use other options, but just stick with this.

**III: GET SIPDROID (I-P-TEL GMBH) VIA ANDROID MARKET**

1) Find and install Sipdroid via Android Market.

2) Open the program. Upon first run, you will see the magical button at the bottom of your screen, which may be covered by a keyboard. Get rid of the keyboard by pressing the back button or hide keyboard button.

3) Tap the "New PBX linked to my Google Voice" button.

At this point, you will be linking a free SIP account with your Google Voice account. Also, as passwords must be the same between accounts, the following situation happens:

- You're based in the United States
- The pbxes.org servers are in Germany (?), and will ask permission to use your credentials to login to your Google accout via their servers

This causes Google to think someone has hacked your account in Germany. If you get this, do not worry.

4) Get details for your SIPdroid account credentials.

- Username: it will be username-200@pbxes.org. (The "-200" comes right after your username)
- Password: whatever password you used to register for the service. (BTW, my pw is hunter2, but you should see stars. HAHAHA.)

5) Uninstall SIPdroid

**IV: CONFIRM ACCOUNT VIA pbxes.org**

1) Login to pbxes.org with your credentials (from section III, step 4).

2) After login, go to "Personal Data" (on the left-hand side). If you don't want your account deleted in 1 week, fill this out. Fill out with your details, or use dummy data if you wish. I'm sure Alice, Bob, John and Jane Doe have multiple accounts... : )

3) GOTO `Extensions`, then `Sipdroid <200>`. In `Device Options`, you will see a `password` field. The password HERE has to match your Google Voice account. That way, pbxes can login to Google Voice. You can also set up your caller ID here, so go crazy.

4) *Optional, but strongly suggested:* make sure that the password to login to the web interface of pbxes.org is different from the one to your Google Voice account.

**V: PUTTING THE SIP SERVICE ON YOUR NEXUS S**

This is where it get's serious. Actually, it's pretty easy.

1) Go to your phone dialer.

2) Tap the `menu` button to get `Settings`.

3) Scroll down to `INTERNET CALL SETTINGS`, and tap `Accounts`.

4) Check `Receive incoming calls`. Yeah, you can be a jerk and only use your phone to call out, but what about the people who want to *phone you*? Just check it. Unless you don't want anyone calling you. And if that's the case, *why are you even following this guide*?

5) Tap the `menu` button and tap `Add account`.

- `Username` and `Password` is what was listed in section III, step 4.
- `Server` is `pbxes.org`
- Check `Set as primary account`
- Tap `Optional settings`. At this point, check to make sure `Transport type` is `TCP`, and that your `Port number` is 5060. You can probably use another port, but it seems to work. Oh wait, port 5060 is the official SIP port. Go to:

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

and search `5060`. SO YOU USE `5060`, AND LIFE WILL BE GOOD. Don't be smart and say "I'll use port--" NO! This is not a storm, you are not a sailor going to another port. You will use `5060`, and you will be happy with the choice. Alternatively, port `5061' is SIP over TLS, but I've never used that and I am not sure if it would work.

6) SAVE the account.

**VI: TESTING THE PHONE**

If you've gotten this far without errors or crying, then try calling a number.

1) Dial your number. From now on, dial with the following format:

```
1 - areacode - XXX - YYYY
```

That way, you don't have to worry about whether or not it's a local call or long-distance call.

At this point, a nifty popup will show. It will state `Complete action using`. Select `Mobile Data`, and tap `Just once`. That way, you can make it permanent after it works properly.

2) Now you get something that pops up saying `[warning triangle] Place call`. You will tap 'Internet call', as you (i) don't have a SIM card in Nexus S.

At this point, it will dial the number. When connected, there will be a bit of an echo. Why? Well, your call is probably routed the following way:

```
Nexus S >> Yankee-land (via Google Voice)

Yankee-land (via Google Voice) >> Deutsch-land (via pbxes.org, via internet)

Deutsch-land (via pbxes.org) >> Yankee-land (internet-phone bridge, not sure if it's the right word...)

Yankee-land (internet-phone bridge) >> Person that you are calling
```

*It sound like there's a delay and echo*

Yeah, because you're voice is going half-way around the world. Always pause to let the other person finish. Do this on your side by waiting 2 seconds before and after any speech.

*But I don't want delay*

It's free for North America (US+CAD). Icing on top? If you have a VPN based in either Canada or the United States, have your Android use that connection. That way, you can be in the UK, have a VPN connection to the US and phone someone in US or CAD.

Friend: "Where are you?"

You: "In `whatever country via VPN connection`"

Friend: "Aren't you paying a lot?"

You: "Yes. Can you wire me USD$100? I'm in central Australia right now, and the wifi from this wild dingo sucks."

Friend: "..."

You: "Yes, the dingo has wifi. It's got a coin slot in it's butth--"

Friend: "I've got to g--".

You: "OK, Bye."

Friend: "Bye."

***THE END***

Answer (score 0):

[Viber](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viber.voip) is a free call and messaging app. Both parties should be on wifi to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Dell voice AKA [Fongo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fongo.dellvoice) gives you a number. Set up your number, log in, and run the app from any device.